# constructs a new Loader from account. using AccountLoader from anchor_lang crate

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust, anchor-lang

i referred this https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/accounts/account_loader/struct.AccountLoader.html for Constructs a new Loader from account.

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use whirlpools::state::{TickArray};

pub fn tick_info(
    tick_account: &AccountInfo,
) -> Result<()> {
    let tick_array0 = &AccountLoader::try_from(&tick_account);
    let tick_array_loader: &AccountLoader<'_, TickArray> = &tick_array0.as_ref().unwrap();
}
```

getting error at line 7, while  constructing a new Loader from account info.

```
Program log: panicked at 'called Result::unwrap() on an Err value: ProgramError(ProgramErrorWithOrigin { program_error: AccountBorrowFailed, error_origin: None, compared_values: None })', src/lib.rs:7:38
```

getting error from this function : https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/0.26.0/src/anchor_lang/accounts/account_loader.rs.html#126

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is giving the `AccountBorrowFailed` error when trying to borrow the data for an account. This means that it's already borrowed somewhere else, so you'll need to drop those references before borrowing again. Or more likely, you can probably reuse a value that's already been deserialized somewhere else in your program.

The `AccountInfo` uses the Rust `RefCell` type underneath for the account data. Briefly, the `RefCell` manages borrows to the underlying data at runtime, rather than at compile time, where the borrow-checker normally does that work.

You can learn more about `RefCell` at https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/index.html